# What changed in PKCS#1 v2.2, and why?

Tags: rsa, standards

[PKCS#1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1) is one of the most used (de-facto) standard for real-world use of RSA.

That's for good reasons: PKCS#1 is well thought, versatile, understandable, has been relatively stable for over two decades, and remains practically secure in its original form, contrary to some other standardized uses¹ of RSA. The major upgrade to PKCS#1, from v1 to v2, circa 1998, introduced OAEP encryption with stronger security argument, and improved protection against timing and padding oracle attacks of a decryption device. V2.1 introduced PSS signature and multi-prime RSA.

[PKCS#1](https://web.archive.org/web/20130731100315/http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/node.asp?id=2125)² was updated from [v2.1](http://mpqs.free.fr/pkcs-1v2-1_RSA_Security_Inc._Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf)³ to [v2.2](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf)⁴ in October 2012, and published by February 2013. Changes include:

- incorporation of erratas (last updated in 2005) to PKCS#1 v2.1 (last updated in 2002);
- additional hashes of the [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) family, including SHA-512/256, SHA-224, and SHA-512/224;
- corresponding algorithm identifiers;
- corresponding test hex constants;
- availability only in PDF format with permission to copy disabled (but who automatically compares to test hex constants anyway?);
- updated legalese on the text (which remains worthless if taken literally, as it is of the form "permission to copy is granted if" followed by a condition that is false independently of what the copier does);
- in the ASN Module:

  - `PKCS-1` was changed to `PKCS-1v2-2` and `pkcs-1(1)` was changed to `pkcs-1v2-2(2)`;
  - in the `IMPORTS` (..) `FROM NIST-SHA2` section, `modules(0) sha2(1)` was changed to `hashAlgs(2)`.

What's the meaning, purposes and consequences of these changes in the ASN Module?

Are there any other technical changes? Is yes, which, and what's their meaning, purposes and consequences?

---

¹ The ISO/IEC 9796[-1] signature scheme was withdrawn for lack of security under chosen-message attack. The first scheme in ISO/IEC 9796-2 lives with a mild weakness under such condition. That's fixed with scheme 2, which is essentially  PSS-R, and scheme 3 which is a variant functionally substitutable to the broken scheme 1.

² Archive page of the website for RSA Laboratories.

³ Copy as published by RSA Security Inc. Public-Key Cryptography Standards.

⁴ Copy as published by EMC Corporation Public-Key Cryptography Standards.

Comment: FWIW the _content_ of PKCS1 is available more stably and reliably as RFCs 2313, 2437, 3447, and 8017 -- albeit [with some typos](https://www.rfc-editor.org/errata_search.php?rfc=8017). Also, 2.0 added OAEP, but PSS and so-called multiprime were added in 2.1.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's merely an update to align the hashing algorithms. There are in fact no real *"consequences"* which might have any negative impact as the v2.1 schemes are still supported. The positive impact is the alignment with FIPS 180-4.

To quote the revision history at page 59 of *"[PKCS #1 v2.2: RSA Cryptography Standard](http://mpqs.free.fr/h11300-pkcs-1v2-2-rsa-cryptography-standard-wp_EMC_Corporation_Public-Key_Cryptography_Standards_(PKCS).pdf#page=59)"*:

> Version 2.2 updates the list of allowed hashing algorithms to align them with *FIPS 180-4*, therefore adding **SHA-224**, **SHA-512/224** and **SHA-512/256**.
>
> The following substantive changes were made:
>
> — Object identifiers for **sha224WithRSAEncryption**, **sha512-224WithRSAEncryption** and **sha512-256WithRSAEncryption** were added.
>
> This version continues to support the schemes in version 2.1